# RewriteRule- regex for selecting a string

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

Sorry for the bad title of the question.

My question is that I want to perform an internal rewrite on the following 3 url patterns only

```
localhost/abc
localhost/def
localhost/xyz
```

Substitution is :

```
localhost/stackoverflow/abc
localhost/stackoverflow/def
localhost/stackoverflow/xyz
```

I tried to write a regex for any of the string -- ^(.*)$. The RewriteRule is below

```
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /stackoverflow/$1
```

But it runs in the infinite loop and searches for url

```
localhost/stackoverflow/abc/abc/abc/abc...
```

I want a regex which will detect any one of the 3 strings only --> "abc", "def", "xyz" which will then get appended to the final url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper approach to detect only those string is to enclose them in an `OR` group `(abc|def|xyz)`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(abc|def|xyz)$ stackoverflow/$1 [L]
```

Your attempt was thrown into a rewrite loop, because `(.*)` matches *everything*, including `stackoverlfow`.  Preceding the `OR` group with `^` ensures that it is only matched at the start of the URI.